# Email link redirect to a specific page

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

I am using my application to send emails with a link, I want the link to redirect to a specific page in my application. I passed the link correctly but when I click on the link in the email it takes me to the home page. It only takes me to the correct page when the application is already opened. I'm on DNN 6.2.6 and using C#. See my code below.

```
ModuleInfo ThisModuleRedirect = GetAllModules("ccc_userrequest");
strRequestURL = setting["DefaultRedirect"].ToString() + "?TabID=" + ThisModuleRedirect.TabID + "&IncidentID=" + objIncident.Id;
```

ccc_userrequest is the page I want to redirect to.
DefaultRedirect is the URL to my application(Takes to home page)

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx?ReturnPath=" + Server.UrlEncode(Request.Url.ToString()));      
 //sample
```